# Loop to delete matching values in a list not working

Tags: c, loops, for-loop

I wrote this code to delete all the elements from arr2 that match with the elements of arr. Can anyone help me understand where did I go wrong?

```
int main() {
    int arr[]={1,2,3,4,5};
    int arr2[]={1,1,2,3,2,5,7,8};
    int count = 8;
    
    for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        for (int j=i+1; j<count; j++)
        {
            if (arr[i]==arr2[j])
            {
                printf("\nMATCH FOUND %d & %d\n", arr[i], arr2[j]);
                for(int k=j; k<count-1; k++)
                {
                    arr2[k] = arr2[k+1];
                    printf("After deletion %d", arr2[k]);
                }
                count--;
            }
            j--;
        }
    }
    printf("\nCount: <%d>\n", count);
    for(int i=0; i<count; i++)
    {
        printf("No: <%d>\n", arr2[i]);
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The second loop is interesting stuff. You say at the top `j++`, and then at the bottom `j--`. What's the idea there?

Comment: Is `j--` supposed to be inside the `if` block?

Comment: @Passerby That's because if I delete an element at index j then to go to the next index I won't need to increment the index value, right?
@AlanBirtles I tried putting the ```j--``` inside ```if``` block as well. I still got an incorrect response.

Comment: @AlanBirtles was right, all the same. Your other bug is `for (int j=i+1; j<count; j++)`. Could you explain why you start at `i+1`? If you fix the starting state of that loop, your program will work.

Comment: @AlanBirtles Thank you so much, it did work! It was logically incorrect. I started with deleting duplicate values in the same list. And I basically forgot that this part should be changed. A silly mistake. But thanks a ton!

Answer (score 1):

If i am understanding correctly, the resulting array should be `{7,8}`.

Then, I think it will be easier to just make a new array. Note that the maximum size of the resulting array can be is the size of arr2. (i.e. when there is no match at all)

```c
#define SIZE 8

int main() {
    int arr[]={1,2,3,4,5};
    int arr2[]={1,1,2,3,2,5,7,8}; 
    int count = 8;
    int result[SIZE];
    int k = 0;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        int has_dup = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        {
            if (arr2[i]==arr[j])
            {
                printf("\nMATCH FOUND %d & %d\n", arr2[i], arr[j]);
                has_dup = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (has_dup == 0)
            result[k++] = arr2[i];
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < k; i++)
    {
        printf("No: <%d>\n", result[i]);
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```